How can I have clients route to advertised Tailscale subnets first instead of the local network?
I have a Tailscale network. One of the devices advertises a subnet router for 10.1.2.0/24, therefore allowing me to remotely access parts of my network that don't have, and are not compatible with, Tailscale clients.
When I connect to the Tailnet on a network that doesn't use that subnet, all is well and I can remotely access devices in that subnet. However, if the local network does use 10.1.2.0/24, then the system prefers to route traffic to the local network and not the Tailnet.
For example, if I have an SSH server on 10.1.2.3 and I'm using Tailscale on a Wi-Fi network that uses 10.1.2.0/24 as its subnet and 10.1.2.1 as its router, SSH connections to 10.1.2.3 fail because the system routes 10.1.2.3 to the local network, not the Tailscale subnet router.
But if I do this on macOS:
sudo route add -host 10.1.2.3 -interface utun8

...where utun8 is the device name of my Tailscale adapter, then the connections work. This of course doesn't help on iOS.
Is there a way to fix this for clients automatically with Tailscale configuration or something else, other than an obvious "don't use two networks with the same subnet?"

For overlapping network addressing, you use NAT (one-to-one NAT, and not the NAPT variant used for public<->private addressing).
